# Reducing modulo $15841$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, carmichael-numbers

I want reduce the following congruence

> $17^{15842}\pmod{15841}$.

My first stab at this was to use Fermat's Little Theorem, but then I realized that $15841$ is *not* a prime number. In fact,

$$15841 = 217 \cdot 73.$$

After some independent research, I learned that $15841$ is actually a [Carmichael Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), $561$ being the smallest of the list. Thus, I know that...

> A *Carmichael Number* is a composite number $n$ with the property that $a^n \equiv a\pmod n$ for all integers $1 < a < n.$

Initially, I believed that the answer was $17\pmod{15841}$, but it turns out that the answer is $17^2$ mod ($15841).$ If so, why is this true?

Comment: Carmichael number or not, you may just compute $17^{15842}\pmod{73}$ and $\pmod{31},\pmod{7}$, then combine the outcomes via the CRT.

Comment: Interesting, not sure if it matters, but $217$ is not prime. In fact, $217 = 7 \cdot 31.$ What you suggested about combining my results via the Chinese Remainder Theorem did not cross my mind, until you mentioned it. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @JohnSmith `why is this true` If $\,a^n \equiv a\,$ then $\,a^{n+1} \equiv a^2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, now that you mention that, you simply multiply both sides of the congruence by a factor of $a$, which means that my final answer is indeed $17^2$ mod ($15841).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any Carmichael Number $n$,

$a^n \equiv a$ (mod $n)$ for all integers $1 < a < n$, therefore, since $1<17<15841$ and $15841$ is Carmichael:

$17^{15841} \equiv 17$ (mod $15841)$ multiplying both sides of the equality by $17$, we arrive at the obvious answer:

$17^{15842} \equiv 17^2$ (mod $15841)$

Comment: Ah. *Now* it seems obvious. Excellent.